# how to get fileList for jquery fileupload plugin?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I am trying to trigger the send action by code, from the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) which looks like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList});
```

But I am having trouble finding out how to populate `filesList`, any ideas?

this is an extract from my html input:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>    
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
```

This is my code try to sendit

```
form.fileupload('send', {
    url: api_urls['wishlistitem']+'?format=json',
    files: $('input[name="image"]',form).files,
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation:

> The second argument must be an object with an array (or array-like list) of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFile) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FBlob) objects as files property.

Create the input type file with multiple upload:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

And in jQuery create the array:

```
var filesList = $('#fileInput')[0].files;
```

Comment: I have updated my question after trying your answer, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesLin Do you have any error? Don't forget `multiple` attribute, if you want multiple files upload.